# How to convert a Set<A> into a List<A1> using java streams?

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

I have a `class A` which is in the client and I have an identical `class A1` in the domain of my project. I have a function which receives `Set<A>` and I want to convert it to `List<A1>` and return. I was able to do it with traditional `foreach` loop.

But how can this be done via `streams`?

```
private List<A1> myDataRep(final Set<A> myData) {
   //Convert and return List.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
return myData.stream()
   .map(a -> new A1(a)) // or however you convert a single A into an A1
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways:

```
class Mapper<T> {
    List<T> toList(Set<T> s) {
        return s.stream().toList();
    }
}


final Set<String> s = Sets.set("one", "two", "three");

// explicit creating a list
assertThat(Lists.newArrayList(s).size()).isEqualTo(3);

// using the stream API
assertThat(s.stream().toList().size()).isEqualTo(3);

// using a class decorating the conversion. it might
// add a bit of convenience, when state is required
// for mapping or filtering
assertThat(new Mapper<String>().toList(Sets.set("one", "two", "three")).size()).isEqualTo(3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could stream your input `Set` and then map each `A` element to `A1` with your custom mapping method. Finally, you collect the elements within a `List` and then return them.

```
public class MyClass {

   public static List<A1> convert(Set<A> set){
      return set.stream()
         .map(MyClass::myMapping) // mapping each A element to A1 with your custom mapping implementation
         .collect(Collectors.toList());   //returning the list of A1 elements
   }

   private static A1 myMapping(A a){
      retun /* ... my mapping implementation ... */
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have a class A which is in the client and I have an identical class A1

I guess by saying identical, you mean that this classes share some attributes, so that information contained in the instance of `A` is sufficient to create a new instance of `A1`.

If that is the case, you can define a constructor inside `A1` class that will expect an instance of `A` as an argument.

With that you method body might look like that:

```
return myData.stream().map(A1::new).toList();
```

*Note*, operation `toList()` is accessible with Java 16, for earlier versions you should use `collect(Collectors.toList())` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change method on map.

```html
Set<Integer> integerSet = Set.of(1,2,3);  
List<String> stringList = integerSet.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

I would define a lambda to map `A` to `A1`

- first create some records (immutable classes for demo)

```
record A(int getVal, String getStr) {}
record A1(String getStr){
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getStr();
    }
}
```

- Then initialize a list of `A's`.

```
List<A> listA = List.of(new A(1, "Alpha"), new A(2, "Beta"));
```

- Define the mapping function (here, simple concatenation).

```
Function<A, A1> mapAtoA1 = a-> new A1(a.getVal() + a.getStr());
```

- Stream `listA` doing the conversion.

```
List<A1> listA1 = listA.stream().map(mapAtoA1).toList();
System.out.println(listA1);
```

prints

```
[1Alpha, 2Beta]
```